# Java. Changing the values of an inner array within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to create a Data Structure design for a simple snake game. I decided to have a dynamic size ArrayList of Arrays holding integers which represent Xs and Ys of a snakes "body". I have a quite bulky solution (with advanced for loop) to the problem of setting new values in an inner array.

```
class ArrayListOfArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create an arraylist
        List<int[]> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

        // populate an arraylist
        arrList.add(new int[]{1, 2});
        arrList.add(new int[]{4, 5});

        // print arraylist before changing
        System.out.println("The value before changing: " + arrList.get(0)[0]); // prints 1

        // This is what I have come up with.
        // the loop changes the values of the first array in a given arraylist
        int i = 0;
        for (int[] intArray: arrList) {         
            if (i == 0) {
                intArray[0] = 9;
                intArray[1] = 8;                
            }
            i++;
            break;
        }


        // print arraylist after changing
        System.out.println("The value after changing: " + arrList.get(0)[0]); // prints 9
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter solution to change the values in an inner array inside an ArrayList? Something like:

```
arrList.set(0, int[]{9, 8});
```

Thanks in advance! I will appreciate any help!

Comment: `arrList.set(0, new int[]{9, 8});`?

Comment: Oh, my ...!!! Thanks Otto! I turns out I just forgot "new" keyword. What a carelessness! :)

Comment: `int[] arr = arrList.get(0); arr[0] = 9; arr[1] = 8;` Better use `java.awt.Point` or such.

Comment: I suggest you create a new class that wraps the two integers, so that you can have `List<Something>` instead of `List<int[]>`. You know you always have two values, use this to your advantage.

Comment: to Joop Eggen,  C-Otto. Yeah! I guess this is a good idea to use java.awt.Point to wrap two integers and have List<Point>. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `=` sign to set new value into array. If you have array inside `ArrayList` you have to get it first:

```
arrList.get(0)[0] = 9;
```

Full code:

```
// create an arraylist
        List<int[]> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

        // populate an arraylist
        arrList.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        arrList.add(new int[] { 4, 5 });

        // print arraylist before changing
        System.out.println("The value before changing: " + arrList.get(0)[0]); // prints
                                                                                // 1

        arrList.get(0)[0] = 9;
        System.out.println("The value after changing: " + arrList.get(0)[0]); // prints
        // This is what I have come up with.
        // the loop changes the values of the first array in a given arraylist
        int[] is = arrList.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < is.length; i++) {
            is[i] = i * i;
        }

        // print arraylist after changing
        System.out.println("The value after changing: " + arrList.get(0)[0]); // prints
                                                                                // 9
```

Comment: 'arrList.get(0)[0] = 9;' Looks very good to me! I will stick to this way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrays better to create `Segment` class that represent one segment of your snake. Something like that:

```
 public class Segment {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Segment (int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setNewPosition(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

with this class you have simple:

```
for (Segment segment : segments) {
     segment.setNewPosition(x, y);
}
```

p.s. after that you maybe to decide create class `Snake` that contains from  sequence of `Segment` instances (incapsulate List presented now to class `Snake`), btw this depends of logic of your game, what methods will be present in `Snake` class.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will try both ways - with Segment Class and with two dimensional ArrayList - Array. I have already created a Snake (which is a single segment so far) with some methods in it.